# C# Get oldest date from directoryinfo

Tags: c#

what I am trying to do is get the oldest date sorted in a list. I have built a method as seen below and it is not returning the oldest date in the first position. The outcome should be: oldest-newest.

```
private static List<FileInfo> GetOldestSortedFiles(string location)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).ToList();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What I am trying to do is sort a directory by the oldest date on top.

Comment: You are sorting by a date in descending order, not by age, so the "biggest" date (newest) would come first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `OrderBy`. `OrderByDescending` would return the newest files first:

```
private static List<FileInfo> GetOldestSortedFiles(string location)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles()
                                      .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                                      .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Apparently working for 32 hours without sleep caused me to over look this. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort by **LastAccessTime**

```
private static List<FileInfo> GetOldestSortedFiles(string location)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles().OrderBy(f => f.LastAccessTime).ToList();
}
```

Comment: But he wants creation date, not access time.

Comment: *What I am trying to do is get the **oldest date**.*

Comment: Yes, in my case I needed to sort by Creation Date. Thank you for your help!